I used condition_variables to fade out the click sound on XAudio2 but it failed
I use XAudio2 to play audio frame by frame through its callback function OnBufferEnd.
When I pause the audio, it has a click sound. I plan to use a fade-out method to eliminate the click sound.
This method involves synchronization issues between the main thread and the XAudio2 thread, so I used condition variables.
I tried to do this, but the actual result is not correct, even though I think the code logic is correct.
I have no experience in synchronous programming. I don’t know if the code is written correctly or if there is some other reason why the click sound is not eliminated.
My idea is that during audio playback, OnBufferEnd is always being triggered. To pause the audio, use the condition variable to pause OnBufferEnd.
Then pause function to fade out the buffer, and then notify OnBufferEnd. Then OnBufferEnd will submit the buffer to XAudio2, and pause function will wait for XAudio2 to finish playing the buffer.
So when the fade-out buffer is played by XAudio, OnBufferEnd is triggered again, OnBufferEnd will notify the pause function, the pause function exits, and the audio pause process is completed.
Here's how I do it by code:
std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool pauseOnBufferEnd{ false };
bool OnBufferEndIsPaused{ false };
bool processingFinish{ false };
bool startToPlaybackFadeOutBuffer{ false };
bool fadeOutBufferPlaybackFinish{ false };

I use these variables for synchronization control between the main thread and the XAudio2 thread.
The following is the code related to OnBufferEnd and pause:
void OnBufferEnd() {
  while (true) {
    std::unique_lock lock(mutex);

    // Whether plaied the fade out buffer on the last loop.
    if (startToPlaybackFadeOutBuffer) {
      printf("Fade out buffer playback finish.\n");
      fadeOutBufferPlaybackFinish = true;
      lock.unlock();
      cv.notify_one();
      // End the OnBufferEnd, the audio is paused.
      printf("Paused...\n");
      return;
    }

    // Whether call pause.
    if (pauseOnBufferEnd) {
      OnBufferEndIsPaused = true;
      lock.unlock();
      cv.notify_one();

      lock.lock();
      printf("OnBufferend is Paused."
             "Waiting pause process fade out.\n");
      cv.wait(lock, [] { return processingFinish; });
      lock.unlock();

      printf("Processing finish, playing the fade out buffer.\n");
      startToPlaybackFadeOutBuffer = true;
    }
    else {
      lock.unlock();
    }

    // Submit buffer to XAudio2 and play the buffer.
    printf("Playing audio...\n");
    Sleep(1000);
  }
}

void pause() {
  std::unique_lock lock(mutex);
  printf("Pause OnBufferEnd.\n");
  pauseOnBufferEnd = true;
  cv.wait(lock, [] { return OnBufferEndIsPaused; });

  printf("Pause success."
    "Start to fade out the buffer.\n");

  printf("Fade out finish, notify the OnBufferEnd.\n");
  processingFinish = true;
  lock.unlock();
  cv.notify_one();

  lock.lock();
  printf("Wait the fade out buffer playback finish...\n");
  cv.wait(lock, [] { return fadeOutBufferPlaybackFinish; });

  printf("Fade out play finish."
    "The audio is paused.\n");
  
  // Reinitialize related resource.
  pauseOnBufferEnd = false;
  OnBufferEndIsPaused = false;
  processingFinish = false;
  startToPlaybackFadeOutBuffer = false;
  fadeOutBufferPlaybackFinish = false;
}

Then I tested it with a program to verify that the audio pause flow worked as I thought it would。
int main() {
  std::jthread(OnBufferEnd).detach();

  Sleep(3000);

  pause();

  return 0;
}

This is the result of running:
Playing audio...
Playing audio...
Playing audio...
Pause OnBufferEnd.
OnBufferend is Paused.Waiting pause process fade out.
Pause success.Start to fade out the buffer.
Fade out finish, notify the OnBufferEnd.
Wait the fade out buffer playback finish...
Processing finish, playing the fade out buffer.
Playing audio...
Fade out buffer playback finish.
Paused...
Fade out play finish.The audio is paused.

Then I used the actual audio code to test it, as follows:
audio.h
#pragma once

#include <xaudio2.h>
#include <exception>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>

class Audio {
  inline static IXAudio2* pXAudio2{};
  inline static IXAudio2MasteringVoice* pMasterVoice{};

public:
  Audio() {
    if (FAILED(CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)))
      throw std::exception("Failed to initialize COM.");

    if (FAILED(XAudio2Create(&pXAudio2, 0, XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_PROCESSOR)))
      throw std::exception("Failed to create XAudio2.");

    if (FAILED(pXAudio2->CreateMasteringVoice(&pMasterVoice)))
      throw std::exception("Failed to create MasterVoice.");
  }

  ~Audio() {
    pMasterVoice->DestroyVoice();
    pXAudio2->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
  }

  // Read file data to buffer.
  int read(int pos) {
    fileStream.seekg(pos, std::ios::beg);
    if (fileStream.fail()) {
      auto state = fileStream.rdstate();
      fileStream.clear();
      read(pos);
    }
    fileStream.read(buffer, BufferSize);
    return static_cast<int>(fileStream.gcount());
  }

  bool loadFile(const std::filesystem::path& path) {
    fileStream.open(path, std::ios::binary);

    if (!fileStream)
      return false;

    fileStream.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    int fileSize = static_cast<int>(fileStream.tellg());

    // Read format.
    fileStream.seekg(20, std::ios::beg);
    char formatBuffer[sizeof(format)]{};
    fileStream.read(formatBuffer, sizeof(format));

    memcpy(&format, formatBuffer, sizeof(format));

    // Read dataSize.
    read(40);
    int dataSize = *std::bit_cast<const int*>(&buffer);

    // Read by frame.
    pData = std::make_unique<BYTE[]>(BufferSize);
    lastReaded = read(offset);
    memcpy(pData.get(), buffer, lastReaded);

    dataBuffer.AudioBytes = lastReaded;
    dataBuffer.pAudioData = pData.get();
    dataBuffer.pContext = this;

    if (FAILED(pXAudio2->CreateSourceVoice(&pSourceVoice, &format, 0,
      XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_FREQ_RATIO, &voiceCallback, nullptr, nullptr)))
      return false;

    if (FAILED(pSourceVoice->SubmitSourceBuffer(&dataBuffer)))
      return false;

    return true;
  }

  void play() noexcept {
    pSourceVoice->Start();
  }

  void pause() noexcept {
    std::unique_lock lock(mutex);
    printf("Pause OnBufferEnd.\n");
    pauseOnBufferEnd = true;
    cv.wait(lock, [&] { return OnBufferEndIsPaused; });

    printf("Pause success."
      "Start to fade out the buffer.\n");

    fadeOut(fadeOutBuffer, fadeOutBufferSize);

    printf("Fade out finish, notify the OnBufferEnd.\n");
    processingFinish = true;
    lock.unlock();
    cv.notify_one();

    lock.lock();
    printf("Wait the fade out buffer playback finish...\n");
    cv.wait(lock, [&] { return fadeOutBufferPlaybackFinish; });

    printf("Fade out play finish."
      "The audio is paused.\n");

    // Reinitialize related resource.
    pauseOnBufferEnd = false;
    OnBufferEndIsPaused = false;
    processingFinish = false;
    startToPlaybackFadeOutBuffer = false;
    fadeOutBufferPlaybackFinish = false;
  }

  void fadeOut(char* buffer, uint32_t bufferSize) noexcept {
    auto bytes{ format.wBitsPerSample / 8 };
    auto samples{ bufferSize / bytes };
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < samples; ++i) {
      auto fadeOutFactor = 1.0 - std::pow(static_cast<float>(i) / samples, 2);
      auto& sample = *std::bit_cast<int16_t*>(&buffer[i * bytes]);
      auto fadeSample = static_cast<int16_t>(sample * fadeOutFactor);
      sample = fadeSample;
    }
  }

  void OnBufferEnd(void* pBufferContext) {
    std::unique_lock lock(mutex);

    // Whether plaied the fade out buffer on the last loop.
    if (startToPlaybackFadeOutBuffer) {
      printf("Fade out buffer playback finish.\n");
      fadeOutBufferPlaybackFinish = true;
      lock.unlock();
      cv.notify_one();
      // End the OnBufferEnd, the audio is paused.
      printf("Paused...\n");
      return;
    }

    offset += lastReaded;
    lastReaded = read(offset);

    if (lastReaded > 0) {
      // Whether call pause.
      if (pauseOnBufferEnd) {
        fadeOutBuffer = buffer;
        fadeOutBufferSize = BufferSize;
        OnBufferEndIsPaused = true;
        lock.unlock();
        cv.notify_one();

        lock.lock();
        printf("OnBufferend is Paused."
          "Waiting pause process fade out.\n");
        cv.wait(lock, [&] { return processingFinish; });
        lock.unlock();

        printf("Processing finish, playing the fade out buffer.\n");
        startToPlaybackFadeOutBuffer = true;
      }
      else {
        lock.unlock();
      }
      memcpy(pData.get(), buffer, lastReaded);
      dataBuffer.AudioBytes = lastReaded;
      pSourceVoice->SubmitSourceBuffer(&dataBuffer);
    }
  }

private:
  class VoiceCallback : public IXAudio2VoiceCallback {
  protected:
    void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnVoiceProcessingPassStart(UINT32 SamplesRequired) override {}
    void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnVoiceProcessingPassEnd() override {}
    void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnStreamEnd() override {}
    void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnBufferStart(void* pBufferContext) override {}
    void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnBufferEnd(void* pBufferContext) override {
      std::bit_cast<Audio*>(pBufferContext)->OnBufferEnd(nullptr);
    }
    void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnLoopEnd(void* pBufferContext) override {}
    void STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnVoiceError(void* pBufferContext, HRESULT Error) override {}
  };

  inline static VoiceCallback voiceCallback;
  IXAudio2SourceVoice* pSourceVoice{};
  WAVEFORMATEX format{};
  XAUDIO2_BUFFER dataBuffer{};
  std::unique_ptr<BYTE[]> pData;

  std::ifstream fileStream;
  int offset{ 44 };
  static constexpr unsigned BufferSize{ 1152 * 2 * 2 };
  char buffer[BufferSize]{};
  int lastReaded{};

  std::mutex mutex;
  std::condition_variable cv;
  bool pauseOnBufferEnd{ false };
  bool OnBufferEndIsPaused{ false };
  bool processingFinish{ false };
  bool startToPlaybackFadeOutBuffer{ false };
  bool fadeOutBufferPlaybackFinish{ false };
  char* fadeOutBuffer{};
  int fadeOutBufferSize{};
};

main.cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool pauseOnBufferEnd{ false };
bool OnBufferEndIsPaused{ false };
bool processingFinish{ false };
bool startToPlaybackFadeOutBuffer{ false };
bool fadeOutBufferPlaybackFinish{ false };

void OnBufferEnd() {
  while (true) {
    std::unique_lock lock(mutex);

    // Whether plaied the fade out buffer on the last loop.
    if (startToPlaybackFadeOutBuffer) {
      printf("Fade out buffer playback finish.\n");
      fadeOutBufferPlaybackFinish = true;
      lock.unlock();
      cv.notify_one();
      // End the OnBufferEnd, the audio is paused.
      printf("Paused...\n");
      return;
    }

    // Whether call pause.
    if (pauseOnBufferEnd) {
      OnBufferEndIsPaused = true;
      lock.unlock();
      cv.notify_one();

      lock.lock();
      printf("OnBufferend is Paused."
             "Waiting pause process fade out.\n");
      cv.wait(lock, [] { return processingFinish; });
      lock.unlock();

      printf("Processing finish, playing the fade out buffer.\n");
      startToPlaybackFadeOutBuffer = true;
    }
    else {
      lock.unlock();
    }

    // Submit buffer to XAudio2 and play the buffer.
    printf("Playing audio...\n");
    Sleep(1000);
  }
}

void pause() {
  std::unique_lock lock(mutex);
  printf("Pause OnBufferEnd.\n");
  pauseOnBufferEnd = true;
  cv.wait(lock, [] { return OnBufferEndIsPaused; });

  printf("Pause success."
    "Start to fade out the buffer.\n");

  printf("Fade out finish, notify the OnBufferEnd.\n");
  processingFinish = true;
  lock.unlock();
  cv.notify_one();

  lock.lock();
  printf("Wait the fade out buffer playback finish...\n");
  cv.wait(lock, [] { return fadeOutBufferPlaybackFinish; });

  printf("Fade out play finish."
    "The audio is paused.\n");
  
  // Reinitialize related resource.
  pauseOnBufferEnd = false;
  OnBufferEndIsPaused = false;
  processingFinish = false;
  startToPlaybackFadeOutBuffer = false;
  fadeOutBufferPlaybackFinish = false;
}

#include "audio.h"

int main() {
#if 1
  {
    std::jthread(OnBufferEnd).detach();

    Sleep(3000);

    pause();
  }
#endif
#if 1
  {
    Audio audio;

    audio.loadFile("Test.wav");

    audio.play();

    Sleep(1500);

    audio.pause();
  }
#endif
  return 0;
}

So the problem came, the click sound was not eliminated, even though the execution logic of the program was what I expected.
But I found that if I add a delay after audio.pause();, for example Sleep(100); then the click sound is eliminated, but I don't know why this is the case.
Maybe there's something wrong with my synchronization code, or maybe it's for other reasons, but I haven't found it yet.
So I want to know what is the problem and what is the solution.
Here is the test audio file I used if you need it.  Test.wav
